# Rails Redis expire method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

If i have a token which expires in 21 days

```
Rails.cache.write token, id, expires_in: 21.days
```

i am trying to write a method to check if the has expired or not. Kindly give me direction

```
def check_token_expiry(token)

end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the `expires_in: 21.days` while caching, you tell underlying cache store to store the data for given key(here `token`) for 21 days, after 21 days it gets expired means data is no longer available for the give key you use `exist?` method to check this.

```
Rails.cache.exist?(token) # => true  (data is available and you read)
Rails.cache.exist?(token) # => false (cache is expired, data is not available)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method will return if the value associated with a `token/key` is expired or not.

```
def check_token_expiry(token)
  Rails.cache.read(token).nil?
end
```

Basically, try to read the value from cache. If it is expired, read method will return nil.